# Будет ли метод работать асинхронно

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, mvc, асинхронность

Объясните, пожалуйста, про асинхронность!

В проекте у меня есть ajax.beginform во View Index.cshtml, в которой выпадающий список и по имени это все отсылается в метод возвращающий частичное представление.

View Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Checkitlink.Models.ViewModels.UserVM>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Список пользователей";

    AjaxOptions ajaxSort = new AjaxOptions()
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "list",
        Url = Url.Action("UsersQueryPartial")
    };
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(ajaxSort))
        {
            <ul class="navbar-nav userDropdown btn-group btn btn-info" style="margin-right: 15px; border-radius: 15px;">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle userDropdown" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Сортировать
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Статус</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <button name="sort" value="user_active">Активные</button>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <button name="sort" value="user_block">Заблокированные</button>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Кол-ву ссылок</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li>
                                    <button class="dropdown-item" name="sort" value="linksCount_asc">Возрастанию</button>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <button class="dropdown-item" name="sort" value="linksCount_desc">Убыванию</button>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        }

<div id="list">
    @Html.Action("UsersQueryPartial")
</div>
```

Родительский и дочерний метод из контроллера

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult UsersQueryPartial(string sort, string filter, int? page)
        {
            List<UserVM> usersList = new List<UserVM>();

            var pageNumber = page ?? 1;

            using(ChekitDB chekitDB = new ChekitDB())
            {
                string SortQuery = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sort) ? "login_asc" : sort;

                switch (SortQuery)
                {
                    case "login_asc":
                        usersList = chekitDB.Users.ToArray().Where(x => x.BanStatus == false).OrderBy(x => x.Login).Select(x => new UserVM(x)).ToList();
                        break;
                    case "user_active":
                        usersList = chekitDB.Users.ToArray().Where(x => x.BanStatus == false).OrderBy(x => x.Login).Select(x => new UserVM(x)).ToList();
                        break;
                    case "user_block":
                        usersList = chekitDB.Users.ToArray().Where(x => x.BanStatus == true).OrderBy(x => x.Login).Select(x => new UserVM(x)).ToList();
                        break;
                    case "linksCount_asc":
                        usersList = chekitDB.Users.ToArray().Where(x => x.BanStatus == false).OrderBy(x => x.LinksCount).Select(x => new UserVM(x)).ToList();
                        break;
                    case "linksCount_desc":
                        usersList = chekitDB.Users.ToArray().Where(x => x.BanStatus == false).OrderByDescending(x => x.LinksCount).Select(x => new UserVM(x)).ToList();
                        break;
                    default:
                        usersList = chekitDB.Users.ToArray().Where(x => x.BanStatus == false).OrderBy(x => x.Login).Select(x => new UserVM(x)).ToList();
                        break;
                }

                if(filter != null)
                {
                    usersList = usersList.Where(x => x.SearchInfo().ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower())).ToList();
                }
            }

            var usersOnPage = usersList.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 20);
            ViewBag.usersOnPage = usersOnPage;

            return PartialView("_UsersQueryPartial", usersOnPage);
        }
```

Частичное представление _UsersQueryPartial.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Checkitlink.Models.ViewModels.UserVM>

@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;

@if (!Model.Any())
{
    <h2>Пользователей не обнаружено</h2>
}
else
{
    <div class="d-table">
        <div class="d-tr">
            <div class="d-td">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Login)
            </div>
            <div class="d-td">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
            </div>
            <div class="d-td">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LinksCount)
            </div>
            <div class="d-td">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BanStatus)
            </div>
            <div class="d-td">
                Действия
            </div>
        </div>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="d-tr">
                <div class="d-td">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Login)
                </div>
                <div class="d-td">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
                </div>
                <div class="d-td">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LinksCount)
                </div>
                @if (item.BanStatus == false)
                {
                <div class="d-td text-success">
                    Активный
                </div>
                }
                else
                {
                <div class="d-td">
                    <a class="text-danger" href="~/admin/user/BlackList" style="text-decoration:none" title="Посмотреть причину">Заблокирован</a>
                </div>
                }
                <div class="d-td">
                    @Html.ActionLink("Инфо", "InfoUser", new { id = item.UserId }, new { @class = "btn btn-info" }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Редактировать", "EditUser", new { id = item.UserId }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" }) |
                    @if (item.Role == "Админ")
                    {
                        @Html.ActionLink("Заблокировать", "BanUser", new { id = item.UserId }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning disabled" })
                        string slash = " | ";
                        @slash
                        @Html.ActionLink("Удалить", "DeleteUser", new { id = item.UserId }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger disabled" })
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.ActionLink("Заблокировать", "BanUser", new { id = item.UserId }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning blockLink" })
                        string slash = " | ";
                        @slash
                        @Html.ActionLink("Удалить", "DeleteUser", new { id = item.UserId }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger delete" })
                    }
                </div>

                <div id="blockUser">
                    <form method="post" action="~/admin/user/BanUser">
                        <p class="text-danger">Блокировка пользователя</p>
                        <p>Укажите причину</p>
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@item.UserId" />
                        <input type="text" name="reason" class="form-control" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Заблокировать" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-top:20px" />
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div id="myOverlay"></div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}

@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.usersOnPage, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
```

Так вот, скажите, пожалуйста, будет ли этот метод вести себя как асинхронный? Насколько я знаю, то метод возвращающий частичное представление нельзя сделать асинхронным, а костыли нарытые на просторах интернета у меня применить не получилось.

Резюмируя, нужно понимание:

1. Будет ли мой код работать, как асинхронный?
2. Если нет, то возможно у Вас есть идеи, как нужно его переписать, чтобы добиться асинхронной работы

Заранее спасибо

Comment: А где здесь по вашему асинхронность?

Comment: что ты понимаешь под асинхронностью в данном случае?

Comment: @IgorIlyichyov, её здесь нет, потому что у меня частичное представление, которое не поддерживает асинхронный вызов. Потому я и пришел сюда попросить знающих людей показать, как сделать метод асинхронным без частичного представления с использованием ajax.beginform. Если у Вас есть практический опыт - покажите, пожалуйста, как это делается

Comment: @Grundy, уважаемый, отвечать вопросом на вопрос - это не красиво, в первую очередь. А если ты этим что-то хочешь показать - мне тебе нечего ответить. Если есть что по существу - рад буду помощи. Суть проста - вернуть в асинхронном потоке метод через ajax.begin форм не используя частичное представление. Если знаешь - помоги, пожалуйста, разобраться. Нет - иди дальше

Comment: @МаксимРыжак, так и не понятно, какой результат ты хочешь и что значит _вернуть в асинхронном потоке метод_? Пока ты не сформулируешь конкретный вопрос, тебе будет тяжело помочь. Поэтому и задаются дополнительные вопросы. Что ты понимаешь под _асинхронной работой_ конкретно в твоем случае?

Comment: Если имелся ввиду асинхронный запрос, так `Ajax.Begin` как раз за это и отвечает. Если что-то еще - то нужно это конкретизировать.

Comment: @Grundy, ага, т.е. ajax.beginform как бы "превращает" обычный метод в асинхронный и ему, соответственно, никакие async и await не нужны и метод будет выполняться асинхронно?

Comment: @Grundy, а под асинхронной работой я подразумевал использование метода при обращении к которому не будет блокироваться поток, если к нему одновременно обращаются несколько условных пользователей

Comment: _ага, т.е. ajax.beginform как бы "превращает" обычный метод в асинхронный_ - нет. Он вместо стандартной отправки формы делает ajax запрос. И это не та асинхронность, про которую ты хотел задать вопрос :)

Comment: на сколько я понял ничего не мешает использовать Task с partialview даже в [справке](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-3.1) есть пункт про асинхронный рендеринг. Уточни версию mvc, которую ты используешь

Comment: @Grundy, mvc 5 использую, а используя partialview выбивает ошибку, когда метод UsersQueryPartial пытаюсь сделать асинхронным. Плюс нашел информацию, что частичные представления не поддерживают асинхрон

Comment: mvc 5 - это уже core или еще нет? Судя по всему в mvc 5 только синхронно можно. Переходи на новую версию

Comment: @Grundy, нет, mvc 5 старее core. До core ещё не добрался. Ну если у Вас нет вариантов, то может другой кто подскажет. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтоб частичное представление вызывалось из асинхронного метода нужно:

1. Наполнить модель родительской страницы данными:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int? page)
        {
            List<UserVM> usersList = new List<UserVM>();
            List<UsersDTO> usersDTO;

            var pageNumber = page ?? 1;

            using (ChekitDB chekitDB = new ChekitDB())
            {
                usersDTO = await chekitDB.Users.ToListAsync();
                usersList = usersDTO.ToArray().Where(x => x.BanStatus == false).OrderBy(x => x.Login).Select(x => new UserVM(x)).ToList();
            }

            var usersOnPage = usersList.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 20);
            ViewBag.usersOnPage = usersOnPage;

            return View(usersOnPage);
        }
```

В родительском представлении добавить рендер дочернего представления с именем cshtml дочернего представления и заполненной моделью:

```
<div id="list">
    @{
        Html.RenderPartial("_UsersQueryPartial", Model);
    }
</div>
```

2. Создать ajax.beginform. Сама форма, например, для поиска:

```
@{
    AjaxOptions ajaxUserSearch = new AjaxOptions()
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "list",
        Url = Url.Action("AsyncQuery", "User")
    };
}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm(ajaxUserSearch))
{
   <input type="text" name="filter" class="form-control form-search-input" placeholder="Search...">
   <button class="btn btn-default form-control" type="submit">
        <span class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   </button>
}
```

3. Создать "прокладку" которая будет обрабатывать запрос из формы:

   ```
   public async Task<ActionResult> AsyncQuery(string filter, int? page)
   {
       var model = await this.UsersQueryPartial(filter, page);

       return PartialView("_UsersQueryPartial", model);
   }
   ```
4. И метод, который будет возвращать результат в прокладку:

   ```
   public async Task<IPagedList<UserVM>> UsersQueryPartial(string filter, int? page)
   {
       List<UserVM> usersList = new List<UserVM>();
       List<UsersDTO> usersDTO;

       var pageNumber = page ?? 1;

       using(ChekitDB chekitDB = new ChekitDB())
       {
           usersDTO = await chekitDB.Users.ToListAsync();
                   usersList = usersDTO.ToArray().Where(x => x.BanStatus == 
                  false).OrderBy(x => x.Login).Select(x => new UserVM(x)).ToList();

           if(filter != null)
           {
               usersList = usersList.Where(x => x.SearchInfo().ToLower().Contains(filter.ToLower())).ToList();
           }
       }

       var usersOnPage = usersList.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 20);
       ViewBag.usersOnPage = usersOnPage;

       return usersOnPage;
   }
   ```

Надеюсь, что в будущем кому-то пригодится!

Comment: судя по всему для mvc5 Это не всегда будет работать https://stackoverflow.com/a/24154588/2881286